# CSVHelper version 2, .QuoteAllFields property gone, what replaces it?

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I've been using CSV Helper fine, I set this property:

```
sv.Configuration.QuoteAllFields = true;
```

To place quotes around all fields. However, in version 2 this property is gone. Is there an equivalent? If not how do we continue to put quotes round all fields?

I can find nothing on Google or in the docs about this.

Comment: According to the documentation, it should still be there in 2.x. Can you the exact version you're using and the exact error you're getting?

Comment: I pulled down the latest version (Nuget v12.1.0) and inspected it in ILSpy.  Sure enough, `QuoteAllFields` does not exist anymore.

Comment: I think this issue applies:  https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1180

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ShouldQuote` replaces `QuoteAllFields`, `QuoteNoFields`, `QuoteRequiredChars`, and `BuildREquiredQuoteChars`.

You can do this now.

```
csv.Configuration.ShouldQuote = (field, context) => true;
```

They just haven't updated the documentation.

Source: https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1180

Comment: Submitted as community wiki, since I'm not the original author.

Comment: Can anyone explain what's going on there exactly?

Comment: What do you mean?  What are you referring to?

Comment: What does this mean: csv.Configuration.ShouldQuote = (field, context) => true; Why is an anonymous function used, can field and context be changed, what is the purpose of structuring it like this?

Comment: It's a lambda function taking two parameters, a field and a context, that let you decide based on those parameters whether something should be quoted.  It is equivalent to `cvs.Configuration.ShouldQuote = (field, context) => { return true; }`.  Field and context are provided for you to make the decision to quote or not quote.  The purpose of structuring it like this is better extensibility and flexibility to quote however you want.

Comment: It doesn't have to be an inline lambda function. The default is `CsvHelper.Configuration.ConfigurationFunctions.ShouldQuote` which is a static method. `ConfigurationFunctions` is a static class that has all the default functions if you ever need to set them back to default. https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/e18a356a6440c9165638aa2cf677f66750a88b1c/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/ConfigurationFunctions.cs#L86

Comment: @niico If this answer was helpful, please consider accepting it.  If not, what revisions would need to be made so it would be acceptable?  Thanks.